# Pip Install Django Windows 10

Tags: python, django, windows, pip

trying to install Django on Windows 10. Used pip install Django==1.8.3 but get the syntax error 'install' isn't recognized. Read about it in a few other places, must use CMD. tried that. Tried Python CMD, tried running CMD from the folder that pip.exe is in. just installed Python 3.4. clicked pip.exe, and the other .exe's there. tried pip install again. nothing. Is this a Windows 10 Issue?

Comment: Try `py -3.4 -m pip install Django==1.8.3`.

Comment: Alright, I tried that in command prompt program files python, and python/scripts but both times I get 'no module named pip'. Doesnt pip install auotmatically with python 3.4? and either way I also clicked pip.exe and the other versions of htat in hte scripts folder

Comment: It seems that pip3 is incompatible with Windows 10.

Comment: Try installing pip manually from an elevated command prompt: `py -3.4 -m ensurepip -U --default-pip`

Comment: That worked. Installing pip manually, but I still had to use the first command you sent. ty

Comment: The directory that has pip.exe (e.g. `C:\Python34\Scripts` is the default when installing for all users) needs to be added to the `PATH` environment variable (e.g. `set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"`).

Comment: I see I pip installed virtualenv tonight using he path as you pointed out here, thank you!!

Comment: Did you know that Python 3 comes with a virtual environment module named `venv`? Check `py -3.4 -m venv -h`.

Comment: No I did not  know. That is good to  know because my progress is not going well. Do you know a good tutorial for windows based dev? everything seems to be on OSX.

Comment: For the purpose of learning Python it may be simplest for you to use Ubuntu Linux in a virtual machine. Then try things out in Windows as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing pip manually from an elevated command prompt:

```
py -3.4 -m ensurepip -U --default-pip
```

Correct answer from eryksun

Answer (score 1):

1) Download Django version you want from this [page](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)

2) Extract the downloaded file

3) open CMD from path of your downloaded file (short way to do this is to click in path bar in your window and type cmd then hit Enter key)

4) Type the next line (change path if need it , I use python 3.4.3 in my case)

> C:\Python34\python.exe setup.py install

5) Wait to finish installation in few time